# Unformatted text only in body, not in subject when send php mail

Tags: php, email, client

i am trying to send php email using utf8 format, the problem is in all my yahoo,gmail or corporate accounts i receive email with no problem, but some clients using yahoo client tell me that the receive this "���������������� ������ ����������������" in body, the subject looks ok, what more should i do?

```html
$subject = 'Τεστ Θέμα'; 
    
    
    $body = 'τεστ τεστ τεστ : '.$var.'. τεστ τεστ.'; 
    
    $host = "1.1.1.1"; 
    $username = "info@test.gr"; 
    $password = "xxx"; 
   $from = "test<info@test.gr>"; 
    $to = "<$email>"; 

$headers = array ('MIME-Version' => '1.0"\r\n"', 
      'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8"\r\n"', 
        'From' => $from, 
        'To' => $to, 
   'Subject' => '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=' 
     ); 
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
   array ('host' => $host, 
     'auth' => false, 
     'username' => $username, 
     'password' => $password)); 
    
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: are you using utf-8-general-ci?

Comment: where u mean to use utf8-general-ci?

Comment: i think you need to include this...require_once 'Mail/mime.php';

Comment: i use this : require_once "Mail.php";

Comment: Could you include Subject: header received in raw format? [Make sure the header is not changed/modified by a passing MTA]

Comment: what u do mean @andrez?